# Has repository update behaviour changed?

Tags: mercurial

For several years, we have been using Mercurial internally (version 3.1.2) on a designated server, which is now being retired.

On a new server, the entire repository has been copied over, and Mercurial 4.0.0 installed. Everything seems to work, but

http://192.168.0.3:8000/?sort=lastchange

we make heavy use of the above command to inform 'pullers' of repositories that have been updated by other users.

It doesn't order correctly, the last modified date of a repository committed to doesn't update (isn't reported as being updated).

I'm stuck!

Comment: I have no idea if anything has changed but are you sure you've picked the right way of doing that anyway? Let's assume you and me and a fellow colleague work on the same project. I've been working on changes since monday (it is now thursday) and just got in to work. My last change was yesterday, wednesday evening. You've just pulled, committed a minor bugfix, and pushed. Our colleague is informed via your system of a new changeset so he pulls. Now I push mine, these are all dated before yours. Is he informed? Seems no, but shouldn't he be?

Comment: The correct way to inform someone of new changesets is for that someone to do a `hg incoming`. It will tell that person if there's any changesets in the remote repository that isn't locally.

Answer (score 0):

It all works fine, the situation arose because of an ignorance of how Mercurial works.

Originally, the parent folder for all our repositories was copied from the old server to the new. After exhausting all other routes, this copy was redone by zipping, copying and unzipping.

(Lasse, one of Mercurial's roles is to inform and manage the situations you describe. We reduce this possibility by knowing which repos to pull every morning, before starting work. Try it!).